# Are there Planeswalker cards in Duels 2014?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

Duels of the Planeswalkers 2014 has a sealed deck format in which you open several packs of Magic 2014. Magic 2014 as a core set contains Planeswalker cards at mythic rare. My question is: does Duels 2014 finally have Planeswalkers? It's hard to tell since one will only ever open so many packs.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://www.wizards.com/magic/digital/duelsoftheplaneswalkers.aspx?x=mtg/digital/d14/decklists) is the full list of cards in the game.  There do not seem to be any Planeswalkers cards.

However, the Planeswalkers are actually your opponents.  Playing through the story you face opponents such as [Chandra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370637) and [Jace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370728).  The likely reason for this is that Planeswalkers are more like players than any other spell.  In fact, when playing, [you are a Planeswalker](http://www.wizards.com/magic/tcg/article.aspx?x=magic/planeswalkers/week1).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I was referring to the M14 boosters you get in sealed play. I think I've already opened enough Redirects to assume that the booster pool does not match live cards.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are NOT any planeswalker cards in the PC game.

Comment: Your statement is confusing.  Are there, or are there not?  Can you clarify it better, please?

Comment: @frank I just suggested an edit that would make it (hopefully) less confusing ;-)

Comment: @Flyto There are multiple ways to read what is written here, hence why I requested a clarification.  I have rejected your edit due to your assumption of a specific reading.